# Arithmetic modulo of negative number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

According to [Modulo of a negative number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number/1100797#1100797)

> "In arithmetic modulo , we seek to express any $$ as $+$,
>   where $$ must be a non-negative integer."

This makes sense to me as we are trying to group numbers into classes from $0$ to $n$.

E.g. If $n = 4$, then one of the following holds: 
$$a \equiv b \pmod 4 \iff \begin{cases} a, b \in [0] = \{4k + 0\mid k\in \mathbb Z\} = \{\cdots, -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, 12,\cdots\} \\ \\
a, b \in [1] = \{4k + 1\mid k \in \mathbb Z\} = \{\cdots, -7, -3, 1, 5, 9, 13,\cdots\} \\ \\
a ,b \in [2] = \{4k + 2\mid k \in \mathbb Z\} = \{\cdots, -6, -2, 2, 6, 10, 14,\cdots\} \\ \\
a, b \in [3] = \{4k + 3\mid k \in \mathbb Z\} = \{\cdots, -5, -1, 3, 7, 11, 15, \cdots\} 
\end{cases}
$$

But according to [Shall remainder always be positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801505/shall-remainder-always-be-positive)

For example:
$$-48\bmod{5} = 2$$
and
$$-48 \bmod{5} = -3$$
are both true because

> "2 and −3 are just two names for the same element" (Means they are the same name for same class I assume)

Hence $r$ can be a non-negative integer which disproves the original statement? I am confused.

Comment: You are confusing some things. $-48\pmod 5 = 2$ as $2$ is in the range $[0,5)$. But, $$-48\equiv -3\equiv 2\pmod 5$$The point is, if one forms the group $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$, the group of integers modulo $5$, $-48,\;-3,$ and $2$ all describe the same number in this group. Often, to distinguish a number in $\mathbb Z$ from one in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we write $k\in\mathbb Z$, $\overline{k}\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Don Wrong notation, it should be $\ {-}48\bmod 5 = 2\ $ (use \bmod in TeX)

Comment: You should ignore the 2nd linked answer and instead read the other answers there (the highest voted answer is often not  the best).

Comment: @BillDubuque I think Mark Bennet's answer provides more clarity for me

Comment: Do you understand the difference between $\bmod$ the binary operation vs. equivalence relation?

Comment: @BillDubuque Is it correct to say that $-48 mod 5$ when used as a binary operation can represent any number in the set $[2]$ and when mod is used to show equivalence relation we find a nonnegative integer $r$ from [0,5) which indicates which set $a$ is in?

Comment: @mathguy No, operations are (single-valued) functions. The most common  definition used for the operation is $\, a\bmod n\,$ is the least natural $\,r\equiv a\pmod n,\,$ which is the remainder $r$ left by $ a\div n.\ $  Then we have $\ a\equiv b\pmod{n}\iff  a\bmod n = b\bmod n.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque That was a typo lol, my bad. I don't think the rest of the comment is incorrect.

Comment: To be honest I do not know why the first citation says we seek where $r$ must be non-negative.  I do not think we do any such thing and we can certainly have negative expressions of residues.  The *remainder* is by convention non negative but is is also strictly less than the modulus.  But the remainder isn't the residue class.  It is a specific element with in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics, one usually writes “$a\equiv b\pmod m$”, and that means precisely that $b-a$ is a multiple (an integral multiple, more specifically) of $m$. With this definition and this notation, $m$ can be any integer, positive, negative, or zero.

Answer (score 1):

The division with remainder is usualy defined from left to right.

As has been said by  other posters.

If $n\ mod\  m\neq 0$ with $m>0$ one asks for the largest integer multiple 
$mq$ which is less than n and the remainder is the difference $r=n-mq$

Hence r is always $>0$

A way to get negative remainders would be to consider division from right to left
instead.

For a given modulo $m>0$ we have  remainders $\{-m+1,\dots,-1,0\}$ instead
of $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$ and $mq$ is the least integer multiple of m larger than n
.

Both definitions are equivalent,

$n=r\ mod\ m$ for some $r\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}$ according to left right division iff $n=m-r\ mod\ m$  which is $n=-m+r\ mod\ m$ according right left division.

In the second system one would get the result of OP's example
$-48=-3\ mod\ 5$ and respectivly $48=-2\ mod\ 5$.

If one wants negative remainders for $n<0$ and positive remainders $n>0$ one can

introduce a shift function which assigns remainder $-m+r=-(m-r)$ to n whenever n is negative

and r otherwise,where r is defined for n and m in the canonical way

Where i have seen negative remainders being used is when considering quadratic congruences
like $x^2=-1\ mod\ m$ which is the same with asking  for $x^2=m-1\ mod\ m$

Answer (score 0):

Operations are (single-valued) functions. The most common definition used for the operation is $ mod $ is the least natural $≡(mod)$, which is the remainder $$ left by $÷$.  Then we have  $≡(mod)⟺mod=mod$.